# Highlight the search keywords on view page returned from mysql query Codeigniter.

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm passing search variable as array to view file where i'm populating description a column from database how would i highlight certain search keywords in my description on view page.

// as my searched keywords are "mobiles in android".

//my returned description row is as // "There are hundreds of mobiles in android."

// how to highlight mobiles and android.

// which are returned from data base what to do with $row['desc'] preg_replace, str_replace tried, imploded the words tried, i replace tried problem not solved.

My Model:

```
public function anything($tbl){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($tbl);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

My controller :

```
$search = $this->input->get('search');
    $tbl = table;
    $data['search'] = $this->my_model->search($tbl, $search); //returned query 
    $this->load->view('search-view', $data);
```

View File

```
foreach ($search as $row) {
echo = $row['desc'];
}
```

Comment: When you output the value of "desc", you want to change the background color of the strings within that, where they match your search strings. Is that correct? 
Perhaps if you also post the code with preg_replace that did *not* work, people might be able to tell you why.

Comment: i have used preg_replace ($keyword )

Comment: i converted $search to array with implode $code = implode(',', $search)  then i add it to foreach statement foreach ($code as $str){ then i added it to  $desc = preg_replace($keyword, $code, $row['desc']);  and then echo $desc; but no highligh something i'm doing wrong.

Comment: No answers yet developers where are you ??

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this..

```
<?php
   $phrase  = "There are hundreds of mobiles in android.";
   $keywords = array("mobiles", "android");
   $replacement = array("<b>MOBILES</b>", "<b>ANDROID</b>");
   $newphrase = str_replace($keywords, $replacement, $phrase);

   echo $newphrase;
?>
```

proof: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c28d9dfd718c921ef83a7a2ae3c922d70068d6d2

EDIT:

I am working on your code, so the solution above can fit to your code.

So assuming that $row['desc'] is the phrase then it would be like this:

```
<?php
   $phrase  = $row['desc'];
   $keywords = array("mobiles", "android"); // or you could do the following
   $keywords = explode(" ", $this->input->post('keywords'); // Or whatever value it is from POST

   $replacement = array("<b>MOBILES</b>", "<b>ANDROID</b>"); // I over simplify things here.
   $newphrase = str_replace($keywords, $replacement, $phrase);

   echo $newphrase;
?>
```